# Uploading stock price data in .txt files and analyzing in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, analysis, stock

I am new to python and have been searching for this but can't find any questions on this. I have stock price data for hundreds of stocks, all in .txt files. I am trying to upload all of them to jupyter notebook to analyze them, ideally with charts and mathematical analysis (specifically mean reversion analysis).

I am wondering how can I upload so many files at once? I need to be able to analyze each of them to see if they are reverting to their mean price. Then I would like to create a chart that analyzes the top 5 biggest difference from the mean.

Also, should I convert them to .csv files? maybe then upload them to pandas? Also what are some good libraries to use? I know pandas, matplotlib, and the math library, as well as probably numpy.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

use glob to read the dir and pandas to read the files.
Then concat them all

```
from glob import glob

dir_containing_files = 'path_to_csv_files'
df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(i) for i in glob(dir_containing_files + '/*.txt')])
```

Comment: Got the following error:  ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

ValueError: No objects to concatenate

Comment: then you path is incorrect, run `[i for i in glob(dir_containing_files + '/*.txt')]` and verify the files are there

Comment: Figured out last error, but got a new one : FutureWarning: Sorting because non-concatenation axis is not aligned. A future version
of pandas will change to not sort by default.

To accept the future behavior, pass 'sort=False'.

To retain the current behavior and silence the warning, pass 'sort=True'.

  after removing the cwd from sys.path.

Comment: Also getting a memory error... I think I have to separate the files into smaller groups

Comment: that's a warning not an error. If the files are too big reach a few at a time and process

Comment: @dergky do you still need help here or has your question been answered?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your text files contain columns of data separated by some delimiter, in which case, you can use [pd.DataFrame.read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) (even without changing the file extension to .csv)

```
data = pd.read_csv('stock_data.txt', sep=",") 
# change `sep` to whatever delimiter is in your files
```

You could put the line above into a loop to load many files at once. Can't say exactly how to loop through it without knowing the pattern in your file names.

In addition to [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/index.html), libraries that I would reach for to do mean reversion analysis are:

- [statsmodel](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/index.html) for model fitting
- [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/) for drawing graphs

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, the columns are only separated by a tab.. is there any way I can do this? or do I have to go individually to every file and add a comma?

Comment: Use `sep="\t"` to indicate that tabs are the separator.